# Python 3 generates error vs Python 2 using decorator

Tags: python, version, decorator

**Using Python 2.7, the following code works:**

```
def AddHex(old_class):
   old_class.__hex__ = lambda self: 'I am a hex!'
   return old_class

@AddHex
class AClass(object):
   """'Empty' class"""
   pass

a = AClass()
print hex(a)
```

**output:**

```
I am a hex!
```

**Using Python 3.6, I get the following error:**

> TypeError: 'AClass' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

How do I make this code Python 3.6 compliant?

Comment: Can you give full stacktrace for error ?

Comment: Python 3 has no `__hex__` method. At all. This is not a decorator issue; you could have tested this without the decorator ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

In Python 3, [`hex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex) looks for an `__index__` function that returns **an integer**. You cannot use `hex` to print an arbitrary string.